# File upload not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

This question is kind of weird because the file upload in not working in my page. There are no error or as such, it just does not store the image file on database. When I upload the image using file upload control in VS2012 it successfully upload and when I click on a button to save the uploaded image to the database then I does not store.

```
<td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
      <asp:FileUpload ID="fuVerifyPhoto1" runat="server" Width="200px" />
</td>
```

When I look into the database it show "0x" in that column. Does anyone had any similar kind of experience or know where I'm going wrong?

In database the column for file uploader is in datatype `Varbinary (MAX)`

And I take values using `.FileBytes`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the fileupload inside of an update panel?

Comment: No, but Yes, I'm using update panel in the form. But I'm sure the fileupload is not inside the updatepanel

Comment: Is it a yes or no? Can you clearity that the fileuploader is not in a updatepanel? Because fileuploader do not work so well with updatepanels

Comment: No, fileupload is not inside an update panel